# How do I learn to effectively transfer to 2v2 hard AI as Zerg?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

I've played quite a few 2v2 games now and started moving up to the Hard AI in 2v2.  I do fine as long as I go Terran, but as Zerg I'm having real trouble.  I find that I have 2 weaknesses in my gameplay:

1)  initial rush survival.
I can't make zerglings or lings/roaches do well against the computer.  I haven't tried going zergling/banelings yet, but even on medium AI unless i have burrow I don't seem to be able to use my banelings effectively.  Going hard spine crawlers is difficult because of lack of early creep production.

2)  transfer to late mid-game.
When I do manage to survive the initial rushes (usually due to a really effective companion) then I'm having trouble getting into an effective late mid game and end game.  I've been really effective against the ai with harassing mutalisks, especially since you can get the AI to ping-pong their troops, but microing that harassment while keeping my economy going and teching up to t3 units is giving me problems.  If I go heavy hydras then I essentially have the same problem.  I do ok until the computer techs up enough that mass hydras just aren't cutting it anymore, then I find myself behind on the tech and economy race.  What t3 units complement a hydra-heavy build?

Comment: The short answer is: practice.  I'll write a more helpful long answer if I have time later.  You really should try banelings though.  The AI favors Barracks play early game, and speedling/baneling helps a lot with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,

> initial rush survival

Spinecrawlers and properly microed speedlings and roaches can really help in pushing back this initial rush.  Force the AI to funnel up the ramp and place the spinecrawlers behind gas and/or an evo chamber.  If you scout it early, set your speedlings outside your base so when they attack you get an easy flank.  Use multiple queens with transfusion to keep everything going.  Remember you can use them even on your spinecrawlers.

In regards to

> What t3 units complement a hydra-heavy
>   build?

I think there is a fair amount of discussion about this but I personally find a lot of use with broodlords.  A tier 3 unit, which is very powerful at wiping a ground army.  I prefer to use them in team games as well.  Excellent base assualt as well as support.

EDIT:  In a recent match between Idra and Drewbie(?), Idra tech switched from Ultra to Broodlord and ended up finishing the matched.  Had he switched earlier, it is speculated that he would have much sooner.  More power to the broodies!

Comment: Since you're being technical...broodlords are tier 3. A bit on how tiers work, at least for zerg:
Tier 1 = hatch + pool. 
1.5 = hatch + pool + another tech building.
Tier 2 = lair + tech building
Hence, tier 3 = Hive + either ultra cavern or upgrading your spire to a greater spire.
Zerg has no tier 2.5 units.

Comment: @en1gmatic325 you are correct that broodlords are tier 3 units, but there is no established rule for determining tier, instead it is determined by convention, see: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3890

Comment: Hm I wonder where I read 3.5 then for broodlords.  I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

1) Personally, when I'm playing Zerg, I put a couple of spine crawlers up as defense, and that's usually enough, but I'm also putting a lot of pressure on their base with my attacks. I've found with zerg, I'm much better if I play more aggressively than Terran or Protoss.

2) Corrupters work well with Mutas. They still have some value without any air enemies because of their corruption ability, but then I ramp production of them up as I'm prepping for brood lords.

Comment: I like the answer about corruptors, I'll try to mix them in more.  As far as playing aggressively with zerg, especially that first rush, isn't it just suicide because if you move out before that first rush, the computer will double team you, and I'm having trouble as zerg surviving the first rush unless it's a team base and my ally takes the brunt of it.  and again, in 2v2 going solo against the computer never works out for me, and most allys want to turtle until at least they're decently into t2 if not well into t3.